# Blogger - How to hide all labels non-specific from my .post-labels on header-post but not on the footer?

Tags: html, conditional-statements, blogger, label

I could already replace some labels that specify the "Category" of the post for images that did, showing them in place of the word, that would be displayed above the post title. But the "secondary" labels that would be within the main category does not have corresponding images, staying in the same position and with the border and image icon (happens when the image does not exist or there is an error), and the written word these sub- categories.
Here is my plan: Show the main categories that have image at the top of the post, above the title of the posts, and "sub-categories", which do not have them in the footer. Already duplicated the element that shows the labels, and the labels have already shown in the positions they want, so wanted a solution  or  to make this correction.

The code I used to replace the labels Main category for pictures was:

```
<div class='category'><span class='post-labels'>
                                    <b:if cond='data:post.labels'>
                                      <data:postLabelsLabel/>
                                      <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
                                        <a expr:href='data:label.url' rel='tag'><img expr:src='&quot;https://sites.google.com/site/kreativtemplate/arquivos/&quot; + data:label.name + &quot;.png&quot;' expr:title='data:label.name'/></a>
                                      </b:loop>
                                    </b:if>
```

Visit [the blog](http://kreativteste.blogspot.com.br/) I'm testing so you can understand by seeing it.

Comment: Once blog is updated, link will be worthless to future viewers. Please add screenshot of blog.

Comment: btw you may want to use a site to trouble shoot your blog. hoem loaded very slowly.